# need to get program files folder, running 32 bit app on 64bit machine?

Tags: .net, windows

I have tried

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) 'Program Files (x86)
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFiles) '<Program Files (x86)
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs) '<blank>
```

but i need to get 'Program Files

as I need to use a windows default program tabtip.exe

Comment: You are still going to end up getting redirected to c:\program files (x86) and not find the file.  You'll need to be more specific what you want to do with tabtip.exe

Comment: I need to show the soft keyboard on a tablet, but i am a 32bit winforms application.
I have found tabtip.exe which shows the soft keyboard, and only shows in processes when on a tablet, with no keyboard.

I could get the filepath from the process but when i do that I get an exception, I also realised today that the french version of windows has a different name for program files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case read the `ProgramW6432` environment variable

```
Environment.GetEnvironmetnVariable("ProgramW6432");
```